# In menu add configuration link

Tags: magento2

In my module i am create one system configuration now i want to add that link in menu i am trying this code:

in acl.xml

```
<resource id="Training_Test::example" title="Example" sortOrder="60">
     <resource id="Training_Test::settings" title="Settings" sortOrder="20" />
</resource>
```

in add this code menu.xml

```
<add id="Training_Test::settings" title="Settings" module="Training_Test" sortOrder="30" resource="Training_Test::settings" action="admin/system_config/edit/section/example" parent="Training_Test::example"/>
```

but using this code its redirect to dashboard

Other link in menu it works fine but configuration link is not working

**[EDIT]**

When i disable Configuration > admin > security > Add secret key in Urls than it works fine but i dont want to disable Add secret key in Urls.

is there any thing to add for this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In menu.xml your action is like this

```
admin/system_config/edit/section/example
```

you have to small change replace `admin` with `adminhtml`

```
adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/example
```

Answer (score 1):

Add bellow code in file `/app/code/Training/Test/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!--
    /**
     * Copyright Â© 2015 Ccc. All rights reserved.
     */
    -->
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../app/code/Magento/Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
        <menu>
            <add id="training::base" title="ProductImages" module="Training_Test" sortOrder="50" resource="Training_Test::sample"/>
            <add id="Training_Test::productimages" title="Items" module="Training_Test" sortOrder="10" parent="training::base" action="Training_Test/items/" resource="Training_Test::items"/>
        </menu>
    </config>
```

Comment: not working its also redirect to dashboard

Comment: have you createa admin controller with action?

Comment: for eg add action="catalog/product_set/"

Comment: <menu>
            <add id="training::base" title="ProductImages" module="Training_Test" sortOrder="50" resource="Training_Test::sample"/>
            <add id="Training_Test::productimages" title="Items" module="Training_Test" sortOrder="10" parent="training::base" action="catalog/product_set/" resource="Training_Test::items"/>
        </menu>

Comment: i dont need to create controller because action is "admin/system_config/edit/section/example" this is system configuration link and please check my updated question its about seceret key

Comment: Are you need menu under STORES -> Configuration -> Advanced ->Admin

Comment: No i have create custom menu in that i have to add link of my custom configuration and i added that but it redirect to dashboard when "Add secret key in Urls" is enable